# Failover HA set up but VM not migrating?

Tags: windows-server-2016, failovercluster

So, I've just set up 2 Windows Server 2016 Standards with Hyper-V and Failover clustering.

I have one Win 10 VM, and, have set the cluster up, and, when I add the VM role it says High Availability is set up successfully.

However, if I pull the plug on one of the servers, the VM doesn't keep running off of the other one.

What am I missing?

I only now realized that this is how failover clustering is supposed to work, that it will just restart the VM on the other node, however, I think I'm looking for something with zero downtime, I guess I'll have to go the quorum way, won't I?

I have an other issue which is that if the VM is running on hyper1 and I pull the network cable on it, then the VM restarts on hyper2 instead of just saving...

However, if the VM is running on hyper 2 and I pull the plug on it, it doesn't restart/move to hyper1 but does remain in a saved state on hyper2.

Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what I was looking for was VM Guest mode actually, as, with HA-only there is down-time when the VMs restart inside the other host.